# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sleep_on_rate_limit'

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I don't have much experience with API's, much less this one with Twitter. I'm trying to resolve a error called "rate limit reached error. sleeping for..." in Python, trying to use the command `sleep_on_rate_limit=True`, in the variable `api` but an error is showing in the terminal, which I don't know the reason or how to solve. Help me guys love u.

Error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sleep_on_rate_limit'
```

Code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerkey, consumerkey_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acesstoken, acesstoken_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, sleep_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Comment: No parameter sleep_on_rate_limit on the documentation https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-v1-1-reference

Comment: So how i fix the "rate limit reached error. sleeping for..." error without this parameter???

Comment: That is not a error. Twitter API is limiting how many request you can do, so the tweepy library sleep before do more requests. Is your application crashing or is just a log message? The documentation have a example of how to deal with rate limits https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html (see "Handle Rate LImits")

Answer (score 0):

`sleep_on_rate_limit` is not a valid parameter for initializing [`API`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/api.html#tweepy.API).

> [So how i fix the "rate limit reached error. sleeping for..." error without this parameter???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042235/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-sleep-on-rate-limit#comment123817349_70042235)

That's a warning that you're being rate limit by Twitter's API and that Tweepy is automatically sleeping the necessary amount of time for you (since you have `wait_on_rate_limit` set). It is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

*sleep_on_rate_limit* is a parameter used by [another lib](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rate_limits.html) other than tweepy. If you are using tweepy, the correspondent parameter is *wait_on_rate_limit*. They behave alike! Here's an auth function I made for my retweet bot that is clean running since last year (please read after the code block):

```
def authenticating(credential):
print('\n\nfunction>>>>>authenticating')
 
"""   
█ █▄░█
█ █░▀█    
"""
    # credential         • <dictionary>                 ○ its keys will be used to authenticate
    
"""
█▀█ █░█ ▀█▀
█▄█ █▄█ ░█░
"""
    # api                • <class 'tweepy.api.API'>     ○ authenticated api

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(credential["api_key"],
                           credential["api_secret"])

auth.set_access_token(credential["access_token"],
                      credential["access_token_secret"])

api = tweepy.API(auth,
                 wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

print(render(f'welcome,', font="slick", background='transparent'))
print(render(f'{str(api.me().screen_name)}!', font="block", background='transparent')) 
# prints name of authenticated user in large font 

print('\nfunction<<<<<authenticating\n\n')
return api
```

P.s.: pay attention to the last twitter api version [(v2)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/updates/changelog) released on August 2021. I had troubles to authenticate by tweepy because of this parameter, and I believe the cause is linked to this new twitter API. **Be sure to use a tweepy version released before the v2 twitter api or you will face unexpected and unexplainable errors**. The most recent tweepy version pre-v2 is the [3.10.0](https://pypi.org/project/tweepy/3.10.0/). They will sure correct the problems for the next releases but for now, some precaution to not break your apps would be good.

Hope it helps you someway =)